# printf statement working for one instance of the same class but not another

Tags: java

this is my first time posting so hopefully all goes well. I am having a problem with the following program.

```
public class Project3 {
    public static String fName = "drum_members.txt";
    private static Scanner fin;
    private static PrintWriter fout;
    private static Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String membershipLength;
        Member m_1 = new Member();
        Member m_2 = new Member();
        Member m_3 = new Member();
        Member m_4 = new Member();
        try {
            fin = new Scanner(new File(fName));
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.err.println("Error opening the file " + fName);
            System.exit(1);
        }// end try           

        m_1.Member();
        m_1.calculateFreeItems();
        m_1.printMember();
        m_2.Member();
        m_2.calculateFreeItems();
        m_2.printMember();
        m_3.Member();
        m_3.calculateFreeItems();
        m_3.printMember();
        m_4.Member();
        m_4.calculateFreeItems();
        m_4.printMember();        

    }
    public static class Member{
        public int id;
        public String name;
        public String nickName;
        public int monthsMembership;
        public String favoriteItem;
        public int freeItems;


        public void Member()
        {

            name = fin.next();
            nickName = fin.next();
            monthsMembership = fin.nextInt();
            favoriteItem = fin.next();
            fin.nextLine();

        }
        private int calculateFreeItems()
        {
            freeItems = monthsMembership/12 +1;
            return (freeItems);
        }
        public void setFavoriteitem()
        {
            System.out.print("Enter new favorite item: ");
            favoriteItem = keyboard.next();

        }
        private String calculatemembershipLength()
        {
            if(monthsMembership < 12)
                return (monthsMembership + "months,");
            else
                return (monthsMembership/12 + " years, " + monthsMembership%12 + " months,");
        }
        public void printMember()
        {
            String months = this.calculatemembershipLength();
            System.out.printf("Member #1 - NAME: %22s, NICKNAME:%22s, MEMBER SINCE: %22s FAVORITE ITEM:%22s, FREE ITEMS PER MONTH: %d\n",
                    name, nickName, months, favoriteItem, freeItems);
        }
    }
}
```

After debugging all I know is that the printf statement doesn't work the THIRD time, it will work the 4th time no problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thanks for your time.

Comment: what you mean 'doesnt work' ?

Comment: You do Member m_1 = new Member(); and later on m_1.Member(); You dont understand constructors

Comment: Maybe your right, but as far as I know I was calling a function on the second statement. It is worded that way because it has to be for the assignment.

Comment: @user3448297 `public void Member()` is a method (function), not a constructor, which is legal but really weird and confusing.  Are you sure it's required to be this way?

Comment: I don't see any particular reason why it would fail the third time.  Maybe we need to see the input file.